# How to get the result from submit.php with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, submit

Hi there i have these HTML forms:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./comments.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="addCommentContainer">
<form class="add-comment-form" id="addCommentForm3" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost" />
<textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="add-comment-submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="addCommentContainer">
<form class="add-comment-form" id="addCommentForm3" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost" />
<textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="add-comment-submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
// $(".add-comment-submit") selects all elements with the class "add-comment-submit", so the "submit" buttons
// .on will handle event binding for the click event on any of those buttons
$(".add-comment-submit").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // 'this' is the element that fired the event, so the submit button
    var submit = $(this);

    // check if the submit button has the "working" class added. this will tell us that someone already clicked it
    // and we shouldn't continue
    if (submit.hasClass("working")) return false;

    // add "working" class to the submit button to prevent double click
    submit.addClass("working");
    submit.val("Working...");

    /* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */
    // do the post, and on callback (simulated with setTimeout) set everythign back
    $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

    // simulate post 
    setTimeout(function () {   
        submit.removeClass("working");
        submit.val("Submit");

        //$(msg.html).hide().insertBefore(submit.parent()).slideDown();

        // simulate getting results back from server
        $("<div>Here are some results or something</div>").hide().insertBefore(submit.parent($(".addCommentContainer"))).slideDown();

    }, 1000);
    });
});
});
```

With this JS after pressing the SUBMIT button on every form appears before it the message "Here are some results or something".

Here is my submit.php:

```
<?PHP 
$message = "Hello world";

echo $message;
?>
```

**My question is - HOW i can make the JS print `$message` on Submit instead of "Here are some results or something" ?


Can you tell me what i have to change in my script so it will work?
Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation clearly states, the first parameter in the callback is the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

    // simulate post 
    setTimeout(function () {   
        submit.removeClass("working");
        submit.val("Submit");

        //$(msg.html).hide().insertBefore(submit.parent()).slideDown();

        // simulate getting results back from server
        $("<div>" + msg +"</div>").hide().insertBefore(submit.parent($(".addCommentContainer"))).slideDown();

    }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks mate it works! Can you please tell me how i can make in submit.php to print the value of `body` instead of Hello world? When i try `$message = $message = $_POST["body"];` It's not printing anything. I think it's not posting data is it possible?

Comment: @ViolinaMilanova: the problem is $(this).serialize(), "this" is the button, not the form

Comment: @ViolinaMilanova: try something like $(this).parent().serialize()

Comment: @ViolinaMilanova: but I suggest you should not bind click event of the submit button, try binding the submit event of the form instead (in this case, "this" is the form). Well, I need to go to sleep now.

Comment: @ViolinaMilanova: if this answer solves your problem. Please mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick. Thank you.